# Separating the content from rquests.text to separate rows

Tags: python, request, web-scraping, httprequest

I started working with the requests module. I don't understand why the output of something like:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.kickstarter.com/")   # kickstarter just as an example

content = r.text  

for rownum, row in enumerate(content):
    print rownum,row
```

would yield a row number and just one character. How would I get something more like the original build of the site (i.e. row by row of what you'll get if you go to the site and hit 'view source')

Cheers!

Comment: yes so obviously the reason is straightforward - content is just a long string and needs to be split to rows with content..split('\n')

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from a webpage, I would suggest using something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

A couple of examples below, check out the link for more examples.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.kickstarter.com/")   # kickstarter just as an example
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print soup.title
print soup.title.name
print soup.find_all('a')
```

[short tut for using Bsoup and requests](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/1872970)

Comment: thanks for replying. i see you still use the requests module, so what does beautifulsoup contribute? tnx

Comment: requests gets the webpage, Beautifulsoup is used to parse it, I have had little experience in web related development but using requests and Beautifulsoup has made a lot of what I have had to do very easy. I added a short tutorial on using requests with Beautifulsoup